# Unable to load Context Configuration by IoC XML inside WAR by jetty-9

Tags: jetty, inversion-of-control, web.xml, jetty-9

I am trying to load my webcontext using jetty IoC.

My war name **git.ctr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war**
My Jetty IoC xml file name ,
**jetty-web.xml** which is placed inside **git.ctr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/**

As per document of jetty is says IoC file placed inside war file can be scanned by jetty-deployer and war can be deployed using XML . 
Link http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/quickstart-config-what.html

My Ioc XML,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">  
  <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps/git.ctr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war</Set>
  <Set name="contextPath">/git</Set>
  <Get name="securityHandler">
   <!-- Either: -->
   <Set name="loginService">
     <New class="matrix.git.ctr.MyLoginService">
           <Set name="name">matrix-aa</Set>
           <Set name="idpUrl">https://10.100.20.83:8091</Set>
     </New>
   </Set>

   <!-- or if you defined a LoginService called "Test Realm" in jetty.xml : -->
   <Set name="realmName">matrix-aa</Set>

 </Get>
</Configure>
```

Please suggest how can this configuration loaded by jetty.